# Cgo: can't find way to use callbacks with const char* argument

Tags: go, callback, cgo

I'm using a C library from Go using Cgo, and all is good except for callbacks. The library has a callback setter, which takes a pointer to the callback function. The callback function is written in Go and exported using Cgo syntax.

Problem: I can make and export function with `char *` argument, but can't with `const char *`.

Code to illustrate:

**test.go**:

```golang
package main

/*
typedef void (*cb_func)(const char *, int);
void callback(cb_func);
void myFunc(const char *, int);
*/
import "C"
import (
        "fmt"
        "unsafe"
)

//export myFunc
func myFunc(buf *C.char, ln C.int) {
        fmt.Printf("Got: %s\n", C.GoStringN(buf, ln))
}

func main() {
        C.callback((C.cb_func)(unsafe.Pointer(C.myFunc)))
}
```

**test.c**:

```c
typedef void (*cb_func)(const char *, int);

void callback(cb_func cb) {
        cb("test", 4);
}
```

Output from `go build`:

```
In file included from $WORK/test/_obj/_cgo_export.c:2:0:
./test.go:54:13: error: conflicting types for 'myFunc'
./test.go:7:6: note: previous declaration of 'myFunc' was here
 void myFunc(const char *, int);
      ^
/tmp/go-build994908053/test/_obj/_cgo_export.c:9:6: error: conflicting types for 'myFunc'
 void myFunc(char* p0, int p1)
      ^
In file included from $WORK/test/_obj/_cgo_export.c:2:0:
./test.go:7:6: note: previous declaration of 'myFunc' was here
 void myFunc(const char *, int);
      ^
```

Without the `const` qualifiers, the code compiles and works as expected.

What can be used instead of `*C.char` to get a const string in C?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Go does not have `const` modifiers for pointers there is no way to translate this behaviour from inside Go code. cgo will always generate headers that do not have the `const` modifier. This is also the reason why your code does not build correctly: `cgo` creates `myFunc` only based on what it knows: `buf` should be `char*`, not `const char*`.

The best way to handle this is to use wrapper on the C side that casts that parameter to `const char*`. In your case it is enough to change the definition of `myFunc` to `void myFunc(char*, int)`. Passing the function to `cb_func` will work regardless since casting `myFunc` to `(*cb_func)(const char*,int)` only adds type information but does not change the memory layout.

Comment: Ok, wrapper is a solution. However, for now I redefined callback prototypes without const's directly in go file (as in my example above). It looks a bit hacky but works too.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue. One solution for the still-needee is to something like:

```c
typedef const char cchar_t
void myNewFunction(cchar_t* data);
```

then use it in go as `data* C.cchar_t`

Comment: Typo: use in Go as `*C.cchar_t` not `*C.char_t` (I would suggest an edit, but the edit queue is full)