# Unable to export go function with const *C.char parameter

Tags: c++, go, cgo

I have the requirement constraint for my work, due to which I need to use a C++ function as:

```
bool f1(const char* str)
{
    //.....
}
```

The function argument needs to be type `const char*`

However, when I try something like following in the golang source code:

```
//export f1
func f1(str const *C.char) C.bool { 
    //.......
}
```

On doing `go build`, I get the error:

```
expected type, found 'const'
```

I tried replacing

```
func f1(str const *C.char)
```

by

```
func f1(str const *C.GoString)
```

This time, I got the error:

```
expression C.GoString used as type
```

I am clueless about how to do so.

Comment: @cdhowie I tried both C.CString and *C.CString. Both of them display the error  ```expression C.CString used as type```

Comment: `C.CString`and `C.GoString` are functions, not types.

Comment: [cgo doesn't have anything like C's `const` qualifier, so you need a wrapper C function that's non-const that gives you the ability to make the call from cgo.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32938558/1256452) Note that you need a C wrapper anyway if the function is actually in C++, so you might as well make the C wrapper convenient.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `const` directly. You have to create a `typedef` of `const char` . And then use that type into your function argument.

Example

```golang
package main

/*
#include<stdbool.h>
typedef const char cchar_t;
*/
import "C"

//export f1
func f1(str *C.cchar_t) C.bool {
    return false
}

func main() {}
```